# Is there a reason GPU/CPU pointers aren't more strongly typed?

Tags: cuda

Is there a reason the language designers didn't make pointers more strongly typed, so that the compiler could differentiate between a GPU-pointer and a CPU-pointer and eliminate the ridiculously common bug of mixing the two?

Is there **ever** a need to have a pointer refer to both a GPU-memory location and a CPU-memory location at once *(is that even possible)*?

Or is this just an incredibly glaring oversight in the design of the language?

---

**[Edit]** Example:  C++/CLI has two different types of pointers, which cannot be mixed.  They introduced separate notation so that this requirement could be enforced by the compiler:

```
int* a; //Normal pointer
int^ b; //Managed pointer
//pretend a is assigned here
b = a;  //Compiler error!
```

Is there a reason *(other than laziness/oversight)* that CUDA does not do the same thing?

Comment: not sure about why it was designed this way, but don't typedefs help a lot with these kinds of issues ?

Comment: @Paven: The idea would be to prevent the compiler from allowing me to assign a GPU-pointer to a CPU-pointer or vice-versa.  A typedef won't help with that.

Comment: It is most probably due to the fact that Nvidia has no control over the the host compiler. nvcc just splits host and device code and leaves the host code to the host's native C compiler. Generating error messages on improper pointer use would require parsing the host C code. While that would certainly be possible (teaching e.g. sparse about the CUDA peculiarities), to my knowledge nobody has invested the effort into this so far.

Comment: @tera: I did not know that - if you add it to an answer (with some links explaining why it's done this way, or at least giving more details), I'll mark it as accepted

Comment: @tera how does this process actually happens? does it scan the whole code? Is there also any good reference on how exactly nvcc works? thank you

Comment: It didn't have to be that way (and in fact the driver API is type-strong in this respect, since CUdeviceptr is a uintptr_t and not void *), so there's no good answer. It is a design choice by NVIDIA.

By the way, in UVA, pinned host allocations pass back pointers that can be dereferenced by either the CPU and GPU.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nvidia's `nvcc` CUDA C "compiler" is not a full compiler, but a rather simple driver program that calls some other tools (`cudafe` and the C preprocessor) to separate host and device code, and feeds them to their respective compilers.

Only the device code compiler (`cicc`, or `nvopencc` in previous CUDA releases) is provided by Nvidia. The host portion of the code is just passed on to the hosts native C compiler, which frees Nvidia from the burden of providing a competitive compiler itself.

Generating error messages on improper pointer use would require parsing the host C code. While that would certainly be possible (teaching e.g. `sparse` or `clang` about the CUDA peculiarities), to my knowledge nobody has invested the effort into this so far.

Nvidia has written up a [document on the NVIDIA CUDA Compiler Driver NVCC](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html) that explains the compilation process and the tools involved in more detail.

Answer (score -2):

All pointers you define are stored in RAM. no matter if it is a GPU pointer or a CPU pointer. then you have to copy it yourself to GPU. there is no GPU nor CPU pointer. it is just a variable that holds an address to a location in a memory. Where you use it is important, if you are using it in a GPU then the GPU will search for that address in its accessible memory, it can be a location in RAM if you had pinned it to your graphic memory.

The most important thing is that you don't have direct access to a location in RAM because the address space in a CPU is virtual. your data might be stored on a hard drive, but this isn't the case on GPU. your memory address is a direct pass to the location. that makes it impossible to unify both address spaces.

Comment: By that reasoning, we should not have different types for `int *` and `float *`.  They are both just addresses of locations in memory.

Comment: Yes they are, they are both 4 bytes.

Comment: 8 bytes on 64 bit systems.

Comment: I didn't ask about unifying both address spaces, I asked about keeping them separate.  See my edit.